# Parse RegEx in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, regex, string, string-manipulation

Suppose I have some Excel spreadsheet with the following column:

> A-345 hello
>
> hola B-389
>
> nice C-6231
>
> what A-12287 who
>
> just A-7819 C-45556

As you can see - I have a text combined with some RegEx consists of  A,B or C, hyphen and some number with up to 5-6 digits. Some of these expressions appear more than once in some lines.

I would like to parse this RegEx (which varies somewhat between lines) to another column. If there are multipile expressions in some line (like the 5th line in my example), then I would like to seperate them by any character which is not the hyphen (space would do it).

Is there any built-in function in Excel that can allow me to do so?
Maybe some VBA script?

I found [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1077930/parsing-a-text-string-in-excel), but I would like to see first whether I can do it without any external add-on or software. Does this specific add-in supports what I need?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @DavidPostill a seperated column with the regex (A-345, B-389, etc.) in each line. if there are multipile expressions in one line (like the given 5th line) then I would like to have all of them in this single column, seperated by space, or a comma.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a built in function, you can do this array formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,IFERROR(--LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))*999,999)),FIND(" ",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""))))*999,999))&" ")-1),""))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when Exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Note:

This will return the first number grouping after each `-`

[image]

---

TEXTJOIN() is available with a subscription to Office 365 Excel.  If you do not have that then add this code to a module attached to the workbook and use the formula as described above:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```